# Using imaplib to log into Gmail using credentials from a file

Tags: python

I apologise in advance, I know this will be a simple answer but I'm not having any luck and it's starting to bug me.

I just want to log into my Gmail account using imaplib and credentials pulled from a file.
I can log into Gmail no worries using:

```
srv = imaplib.IMAP_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
srv.login("bob@gmail.com", "mypassword")
```

But instead I'm trying to use a text file (credentials.dat). Inside the file is 2 lines:

```
bob@gmail.com
mypassword
```

My code is as follows:

```
import imaplib
CREDS = open("credentials.dat", "r")

account = CREDS.readline()
password = CREDS.readline()

srv = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
srv.login(account, password)
```

When I run it I get the followign error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/imaplib.py", line 480, in login
       typ, dat = self._simple_command('LOGIN', user, self._quote(password))
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/imaplib.py", line 1028, in _simple_command
       return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/imaplib.py", line 865, in _command_complete
       raise self.error('%s command error: %s %s' % (name, typ, data))
       imaplib.error: LOGIN command error: BAD ['Failed to parse your command      r13if7033890ebd.47']
```

I assume it doesn't like the data type being entered into srv.login, but I have no idea how else to do it.

There are so many more things I want to do once I get into Gmail (read emails, post, etc), but it's looking like an uphill battle if I can't even log in :(

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`readline()` includes the newline character at the end of the line, so you're really saying: login with `'bob@gmail.com\n'`

Try `readline().strip()` to strip whitespace characters from both sides of the line.

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean. The comment "excellent, thank you" was my answer. Meaning that adding .strip() worked perfectly.